# Continuous Deployment with Bitbucket and Jazzhub

Tags: bitbucket, ibm-cloud, continuous-deployment, devops, ibm-jazz

1. How do I do **Continuous Deployment** with a **private** `Bitbucket` git repo on `Jazzhub` (IBM Bluemix)?

   - I've already tried: [https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/27490](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/27490/jazzhub-bitbucket/)
   - However it doesn't work in a Continuous Deployment way.

---

2. I made some research and I found this link: [https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/9480](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/9480/can-i-use-ssh-keys-for-password-less-git-operations.html)

   - I fear that the SSH protocol is not implemented on Jazzhub and that the Continuous Deployment can't be possible.

Answer (score 0):

as described in the answer you linked, it is possible to link your bitbucket repo to your jazzhub git set, setting the Bitbucket repository as remote origin.

Can you describe which kind of error you are getting?

About ssh, in this moment bluemix/jazzhub doesn't not supported git over ssh, but it supports git over https only.